# I got this error White label Error Page while mapping multiple index into spring boot controller while trying to display more than one page

Tags: spring-boot

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "myAccount";
}

@RequestMapping("/myAccount")
public String myAccount() {
    return "myAccount";
}
}
```

[Project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6QEF.png)

The above controller exposes two links which return the same html page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please check the stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions

Comment: What is the error you facing here?

Comment: i'm sorry this is the code of my controller                                                                                         @Controller
public class HomeController 
{
 
 @RequestMapping( value = "/")
 public String index() {
     return "index";
 }
 
   @RequestMapping( value = "/myAccount") 
   public String myAccount() { return "myAccount"; 
  }
   the problem is that i couln't map to myAccount Page  while writing its url http://localhost:8080/myAccount

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for my question,
mapping error occurred  because of creating common  header in src/main/resources/static
and in my controller during request mapping  i couldn't  get the page  in static templates which i need to map it within  the controller